# Could Congress create a court higher than the Supreme Court?

Tags: united-states, us-constitution, us-supreme-court, court, federal-courts

Could Congress create a court that could overrule SCOTUS decisions?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### No

> The judicial Power of the United States, shall be vested in one supreme Court, and in such inferior Courts as the Congress may from time to time ordain and establish.

Any courts the Congress creates are, by definition, inferior.

Of course, Congress can overrule a SCOTUS decision by passing a law to that effect,unless the decision defines a right under the Constitution. So they couldn’t overturn *Roe* but they could overturn *Dobbs*. It’s largely the gutlessness of Congress in grappling with controversial issues that has put SCOTUS in the position of lawmaker.

Comment: It's no so much gutlessness as institutional paralysis stemming from polarization.

Comment: @phoog, and our do-nothing system of government

Comment: Is there a typo in here somewhere? I can't parse this: "…Congress can overrule a SCOTUS decision by passing a law **that effect** unless the decision defines a right…"

Comment: I watched a YT video this morning, "Why is Our Government so Inefficient" (or something to that effect) that does a decent job of explaining the tug-of-war of interests that, well, makes our [tag:united-states] government so inneficient.

Comment: @erickson I think it's supposed to say "to that effect."

Comment: @Mindwin what exactly makes innefficient?

Comment: @erickson: Many Supreme Court decisions serve to fill in gaps where a statute as written is ambiguous, essentially saying "since the Statute could be read as saying X, or it could be read as saying Y, we're going to say that it should be treated as saying X".  Such decisions should not be viewed as the Court taking power away from Congress, but rather saying "If you want the statute to be interpreted as saying Y, you need to write it to *actually* say Y".  If Congress does so, some people would viewsuch action as "overruling" the Court, but should merely be seen as Congress doing its job.

Comment: It's worth noting that essentially all the important social "rights" were actually created by SCOTUS instead of being legislated, Loving vs. Virginia, Brown vs. Board of education, Obergefell vs. Hodges, Griswold vs. Connecticut. All decided by 9 guys/gals on a court instead of a reasonable public debate and elected officials doing their job.

Comment: @TigerGuy Our "Do nothing" system of government was created that way *by design*. Perhaps a design change is warranted - but the initial intention was to prevent 180 degree policy reversals every single time one party took power. Congress is an easy target, particularly when things don't seem to be going your way, but slow and deliberate is exactly how things are supposed to be.

Comment: [Article III Section 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_Three_of_the_United_States_Constitution#Section_1:_Federal_courts), if anyone's curious.

Comment: @DRF or by 9 people on the court pointing out the logical consequences of the constitution's guarantee of equal protection.

Comment: @David Siegel, Why did you reintroduce the extraneous words? (To what effect???? No "effect" was mentioned anywhere.)

Comment: @ikegami "*to **that** effect*" (not "to what effect") means "for that purpose". It means that only a law designed to overrule a Court dcision will actually overrule it. It is in no way ."extraneous".

Comment: @David Siegel, Yes, but for which purpose. No purpose was mentioned. "That" must refer to something. Unless you're saying the sentence is of the form "The SCOTUS can do A by doing A". That's a silly sentence. "The SCOTUS can do A" is better.

Comment: @phoog The claim that all of these are logical consequences of equal protection is just one opinion. I don't see how equal protection makes it obvious that there is a right to abortion. And let's be realistic most people in the US don't think so (even mid term unrestricted abortion is opposed by over 50% of people, see https://news.gallup.com/poll/235469/trimesters-key-abortion-views.aspx ). I'm personally in favor of second trimester abortions for medical reasons involving both mother and child, and including mental reasons, but even that is a minority view.

Comment: @phoog Trying to claim these results are all "logical" results of equal protection is utterly unhelpful, and given that the current court doesn't think they are shows exactly why it's unhelpful. I know painting the current justices as monsters who are in some way obviously morally corrupt makes it easier to be angry, but it just means you end up with a completely divided nation where you are incapable of having reasonable debates and attempts at compromise. In that case maybe you should just go and have the US split into two halves.

Comment: @DRF my comment does not only concern abortion, nor even particularly concern abortion.  The comment to which it is a response mentioned "Loving vs. Virginia, Brown vs. Board of education, Obergefell vs. Hodges, and Griswold vs. Connecticut."  None of these has to do with abortion.

Comment: @NeilMeyer you'd need to watch the video, I believe you can find it from the description I gave. But basically the checks and balances and the division of responsibilities generate extra costs.

Answer (score 1):

To the title question: sort of.

Congress has almost complete control over the appellate authority of both SCOTUS and other federal courts; indeed they control the very existence of federal courts other than SCOTUS.  Only those matters specifically enumerated in the constitution are immune from control.  [They can remove anything else](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jurisdiction_stripping#Other_relevant_Supreme_Court_cases), [even for cases that are currently under their consideration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ex_Parte_McCardle).  SCOTUS has upheld this, asserting that it only has mandatory jurisdiction over those things expressly enumerated in the constitution, or on general matters of deciding constitutionality. So they could decide if a law that strips them or another court of jurisdiction is constitutional, but if they determine that it is then that jurisdiction is stripped and the relevant courts, potentially including themselves, cannot hear or rule on the case.

As such, Congress could, in principle, create a de facto "new" SCOTUS by stripping the SCOTUS of jurisdiction and granting it to some other court, or none at all. And they've tried the none at all option before! To my knowledge, those of any particular substance and extent have all been overturned as creating some other constitutional issue, though. The most recent example is the [Military Commissions Act of 2006](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_Commissions_Act_of_2006), which was a direct attempt by Congress to stop all federal courts from hearing cases from Guantanamo detainees. This was ruled unconstitutional in [*Boumediene v. Bush*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boumediene_v._Bush). The implication seems to be that stripping the entire federal judiciary of jurisdiction is likely to be a problem; but stripping just some of the federal judiciary can be okay.  As such it is possible, though far from clear, that this proposed "new SCOTUS" would be upheld as constitutional.  However, they still could not overrule SCOTUS on anything, including what is/isn't constitutional.  Its place in the federal judiciary would just present a greater obstacle to the involvement of SCOTUS in cases going forward; as a side effect this would probably also make it harder for SCOTUS to overrule itself.